# Не открываются проекты через Open Server

Tags: windows

Суть проблемы в проектах. Сам Open Server успешно запускается, но при попытке открыть страницу http://localhost/ через этот флажок, ничего не происходит. Я могу перейти на страницу в ручную, но хотелось бы узнать, что не так.

Answer (score 0):

видимо openserver не знает с какого браузера открывать, поэтому установите в настройках openserver, браузер по умолчанию и путь к нему (до вашего избранного браузера)  далее у вас ссылка будет открываться в указанном браузере